# How to get the current size of an image within a picturebox

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have an imagebox of which I have an image in - I am "Zoom" as the SizeMode (as seen below):

```
this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
```

Now I am attempting to get the current size of the image (when it has been scaled) - not the actual size of the image. For example if I do:

```
var size = pictureBox1.Image.Size
```

This returns the real dimensions of the image - not the scaled ones. How can you get the scaled size of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `pictureBox1.ClientSize`